# How to create fluid trapezoid image with css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am working on a website on which we have use parallax effect. In that there are some images which are triangle shaped, like this [image]

& the image is transparent because it overlaps the above DIV. I am trying so many things with css. but didn't get the desired result. I achieve that desired result with fixed width. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/eJ7Sf/2/   but does not work with fluid width. Check what i still try but didn't work

http://jsfiddle.net/ceGGN/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/eJ7Sf/1/

*NOTE: i know about css3 [MASK](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Masks/Masks.html) property but it's not work in firefox previous browsers. I want the capability till **firefox 3.6.13***

Comment: Why are you including `-moz-`, `-webkit-` and `-o-` options, but leaving out `-ms-`? IE9 is perfectly capable of handling transforms, you know.

Comment: @Kolink first i considered to achieving the desired result. After that i will tested on others browsers

Comment: By that reasoning you only need the one you're actually testing on...

Comment: I may be the only one, but I'm not sure exactly what you want. You want it to scale up and down in size while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Updated Answer (Pure CSS3)

**Extreme requirements sometimes need extreme solutions.** I've built upon my original answer (below) to make a *pure css solution* that works (and can be made to work better, if you want to invest the time in it). The [current example](http://jsfiddle.net/ceGGN/47/show/) is a bit "choppy" in rendering, which may be okay for you, but if not, you will need to extend [the already obscene number of `@media` queries](http://jsfiddle.net/ceGGN/47/) that are driving it (it would likely be much easier to implement using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/); I put together a formula driven excel spreadsheet to help rapidly generate the numbers). It uses this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
   <img src="yourImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    height:300px;  
    min-width: 100px; /*could be different, but you ought to have some min*/
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;   
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Firefox */
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Opera */
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

/*Sample... you need alot of these--my fiddle example has 51*/
@media screen and (min-width:  100px) { 
  .box { 
    -ms-transform:skewY(45deg); 
    -moz-transform:skewY(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewY(45deg); 
    -o-transform:skewY(45deg); 
    transform:skewY(45deg); 
  } 
  .box img { 
    -ms-transform:skewY(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform:skewY(-90deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewY(-90deg); 
    -o-transform:skewY(-90deg); 
    transform:skewY(-90deg);
  }
}
```

**Here's how to calculate the degrees**

Assuming `height: 300px` with the narrow side *approximately* `100px` tall and equal angles on the trapezoid. This means the upper and lower offset is `(300px - 100px) / 2 = 100px`. Then the `.box` angles are set off the `@media` query `min-width` amounts according to this formula:

```
Angle = arctan(100/min-width) /*100 is the upper/lower offset as above*/
```

For the `.box img` angle take the `Angle` and multiply by `-2`. So that will yield your `.box` and `.box img` media queries and transforms as this *pseudocode*:

```
@media screen and (min-width: [your target min-width]) { 
  .box {transform: skewY(Angle)}
  .box img {transform: skewY(-2*Angle)}
}
```

***How smooth it functions*** depends completely upon how micro scale you make your changes to `min-width` to get a new angle setting. As I stated in my comment in the CSS code above, my example uses 51 media query calls and still has some choppiness to it.

Would it be better to use some javascript solution instead... probably, but that is totally up to the designer, so *I offer this here as purely a proof of concept that it can be made to work with pure css*.

### Original Answer

[This seems to be achieving a fluid width.](http://jsfiddle.net/ceGGN/38/) I don't know how much control you want of either how much or what part of the image is being shown, so it may not entirely fit your needs, but it does make a flexible width image using transforms to give it a fake perspective look.

Comment: when you increase the size of the window that become pure triangle. But not that what i want. See the images. But thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @sandeep--so you want the height at the left and right to always be the same? By the way, that is really not a triangle (like your title states) but a trapezoid.

Comment: @sandeep--_or_ does the height of each side change as the width changes? In other words, do you intend the angle to change only, or the angle to be fixed and the height to change in response to the width changing (one of the two has to change).

Comment: height is same & it's look like a trapezoid

Comment: @sandeep--I updated my answer. It works, but I'll let you determine if it is worth it or not, especially if you want to make it smoother in rendering.

Answer (score 5):

### With SVG clip-path

You can achieve this shape with an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) and the [clipPath element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) :

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <polygon points="10 0, 10 6.7, 0 4.7, 0 2" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

### With CSS clip-path

You can also achieve this shape with the [CSS clip-path property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). Browser support is pretty low (see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)) but it is an easy approach.
Here is an example :

```css
img{
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0% 20%, 100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 80%);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 20%, 100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 80%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you play a bit with `pseudoelements` and `2DTransforms` ([supported since Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform)) you can achieve this effect : http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/T5KPA/1/

I tried on Chrome and Firefox. *For Opera and IE9 you need to add proprietary prefixes*.

Markup is really essential:

```
<figure class="triangle">
    <img src="http://cssglobe.com/lab/angled/img.jpg">
</figure>
```

and the css to obtain this effect:

```
img { display: block; }

.triangle { 
   position   : relative; 
   overflow   : hidden; 
   padding    : 0; margin: 0; 
   display    : inline-block; 
}

.triangle:after,
.triangle:before {
   content    : "";
   position   : absolute;
   z-index    : 2;
   left       : -50%;
   width      : 200%;
   height     : 40%;
   display    : block;
   background : #fff;   
}

.triangle:before {
    top: -24%;  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.triangle:after {
    bottom: -24%;  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

I coloured the rotated pseudoelements using white but, of course, you can change the color so it fits the real background color

Comment: @sandeep, this kind of solution could be acceptable or it should be refined more?

Comment: sorry, this not fluid . Which i want

Comment: please could you explain further? How can I modify my example to see how is not working?

Comment: I want the same effect with fluid width means if the screen size increase the image is also increase but shape look like same as current.

Comment: I added width:100% both for figure and img. try http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/T5KPA/4/ and resize the window

Comment: if you also set height: 100% to img and figure this size depends on parent height. but if you use relative size (in %) you should get a fluid element

Comment: sorry you give background color to :after & :before. As i clearly define in my question i used parallax effect. which means when you scroll then image it's overlap the above element content

Comment: I think it's the most you can obtain with css only... if you need both full transparency and fluid design I think it's not possible unless you skew the image