# Firefox and Opera rendering border incorrectly

Tags: css, firefox, border, shapes

I have created a [circular menu](http://codepen.io/joexadrez/pen/cDgfo) using trapezoids made with pure CSS, but when I rotate them, Firefox shows a line in both sides and, on Opera, all trapezoids have a weird background/border-color, kind of transparent. The trapezoids [look like this](http://codepen.io/joexadrez/pen/GByhd).

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 100px;  height: 0px;
  margin: 55px auto 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 140px solid black;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  transition: rotate (100deg);
}
```

Chrome and IE9 are OK.
How can I find a way to fix this?

Comment: Although I hate over-use of css, I do applaud your creative-ness :)

Comment: Seems like a rendering issue. There's no problem with a [90deg](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/kLiKc) rotation in FF. I think you'll have to either open a bug in opera/ff bug-tracker or find an alternative.

Comment: simply amazing. Is it copyrighted or can I use it?

Comment: @DamienOvereem thanks! This was my first try with sass and compass!

Comment: @Kraz is the alternative that I am looking for!

Comment: @Jawad sure you can use! Just let me know when its released in the wild!

Comment: The alternative I had in mind is using images instead of CSS, but I think you'd probably prefer to avoid that.

Comment: If you're interested, i [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818109).

Comment: @Kraz thats what I think. I will use images as my last resource..

Comment: +1 for the creative awesomeness :D

Comment: This problem still exists (or has returned) in firefox..

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use -moz for Firefox; -o for Opera.  Those are the extensions to correctly format within those browsers. [A great site for shapes here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

```
.trapezoid 
{ 
        border-bottom: 100px solid red; 
        border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
        border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
        height: 0; 
        width: 100px; 
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Firefox 4 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera */

}
```

Also I'm not sure if your trying to alter an effect of some sort; but the transition code would look like this:

```
  transition:width 2s, height 2s;
 -moz-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -moz-transform 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
 -webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -o-transform 2s; /* Opera */
```

Just add the transition before hand; then throw the transform on a hover.  If your trying to add it like a button.  Hopefully that helps.

I've used Firebug to view some additional data; with Firefox 16.02 this code worked:

```
.trapezium
{
  height: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  border-bottom-width: 80px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #2d9dcd;
  border-left-width-value: 40px;
  border-left-style-value: solid;
  border-left-color-value: transparent;
  border-right-width-value: 40px;
  border-right-style-value: solid;
  border-right-color-value: transparent;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I believe that is what you are looking for. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Okay, I modified the code.  It works in Firefox; I didn't test Opera.  Opera uses it's own extension.  So you may have to use the `-o` extension.  Also depending on the version of Firefox, Gecko changed certain commands. `-moz-border-left` is a depreciated extension; border left is the current extension. Let me know if that works.

Comment: transform and transition were apparently already [unprefixed in Firefox 16](http://paulrouget.com/e/unprefixing-in-firefox-16/)

Comment: @Greg I learn the trapezoid code from that same site! But the code didn't work.

Comment: Are you just trying to create an animation; or create a 3D shape? What exactly are you attempting to do? There is this article where they turned an image into a trapezoid out of raw CSS3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886337/how-to-create-fluid-trapezoid-image-with-css

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using; as it appears to work for me?

Comment: @Greg I'm using Firefox 16.0.2, my goal is render this menu http://codepen.io/joexadrez/pen/cDgfo properly on Firefox and Opera. If I put the -values sufixes, did't work as well, it just draw a square.

Edit: I have updated my Firfox to 17.0.1 and nothing changes.
BTW, thanks for the help!

Comment: That is a very, very cool menu.  When I finish repairing these databases that came across my desk I'll take a look see if I can find anything.

Comment: Sorry it's been a bit; I haven't had a chance to look at your menu.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the vendor prefixes are missing.
Apply the vendor prefixes as following and you will get it right.

Transition property is used to set and time the transitions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

```
.trapezoid {
  width: 100px;  height: 0px;
  margin: 55px auto 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 140px solid black;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(100deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(100deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);
    transform: rotate(100deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Sass with Compass, so all the vendor prefixies are applied. That's not the problem.