# How to create trapezoid div with background repeat

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want make a image background like this in a div like the following image.
but I can't find any appropriate css or js properties for this.
Is anyone can help to find out how this possible ?

[image: trapezoid background]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886337/how-to-create-fluid-trapezoid-image-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CSS 3D Transforms. Here's the webkit way of doing it, tweak the angle and perspective as needed. You'll have to find something equivalent for other browsers, I don't think it's fully standardized yet.

Just apply this CSS to your div with the background image. I tested this with the lovely stackoverflow logo at the top of this page, which is a div with a background image.

Edit: And here, a red border too. Don't know if its part of the image or you need CSS for it as well.

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateY(-60deg);
border: 3px red solid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you

Transform properties of css

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution and solved the problem with the help of Cubicle Dragon like following-

HTML code

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#div2 {
  background: url("") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(-234deg);
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  perspective: 89px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
```