# CSS create this shape as background only, content remain straight

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a perspective skew shape like in the fiddle below and struggling. So far I can get the perspective working correctly however I can't seem to get the bottom left to be more like a trapezoid shape. The closest I have found is: [How to create fluid trapezoid image with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886337/how-to-create-fluid-trapezoid-image-with-css) but this is for images.

Code is:

```
<div class="we-are">
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
```

```
.we-are {
background-color: orange;
height:450px;
-ms-transform:skewY(10deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:skewY(10deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:skewY(10deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:skewY(10deg); /* Opera */
transform:skewY(10deg);
padding:15px;
}
.we-are p {
padding-top: 125px;
-ms-transform:skewY(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:skewY(-10deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:skewY(-10deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:skewY(-10deg); /* Opera */
transform:skewY(-10deg);
}
```

Current fiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/x6bkbeqc/

Thanks

Comment: do you want this - http://jsfiddle.net/x6bkbeqc/1/ ??

Comment: No - both right corners should be closer together than the left ones :)

Comment: this one - http://jsfiddle.net/x6bkbeqc/2/ ??

Comment: Thats it! how do you keep the background left as opposed to moving right?

Comment: gonna post it as answer and explain in that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole thing for a trapezium shape can be done using `perspective` and `rotateY`. Just wrap all your things in a `div` like -

```
<div id="persp">...</div>
```

and then use this CSS to apply perspective field to the `div`

```
#persp {
    perspective: 200px;
}
```

(adjust `200px` according to your needs)
after that just rotate your `.we-are` along X, Y or Z-axis whichever you prefer (feel free to experiment).

```
.we-are {
    transform:rotateY(10deg);
    perspective: 200px; /* mention this to make the contents of p appear straight */
}
/* and this too */
.we-are p {
    padding-top: 125px;
    transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6bkbeqc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

hi you can achieve your expected result by make this by just adding this css property to the **.we-are p**  selector.

then you no need to change the height or width or include other properties

> **The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.**

**refer this document [Refer](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)**

```css
 display: initial;
```

and here i have updated your demo

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6bkbeqc/3/)**

Comment: Just for your information, OPs always get a notification when an answer is added and so there is no need to add a comment. Moreover, doing @user won't help you either because they aren't part of this comment thread and so won't be pinged :)

Comment: sure i will apply this from now bdw thanks for the giving suggestion @Harry.