# How to overlap onself images with css?

Tags: image, overlap

Question is simple how to do it. 
There is no simple answer on Stack overflow.

We have two pictures. They overlap under an angle. 
These images should also be responsive.

Example picture here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV9fI.jpg]

I have no idea with position absolute or something ? The biggest problem is the angle of overlap. Maybe solution in svg or jquery ? But when they scaling text on them disappears.

Comment: link missing for example?

Comment: Here is example: https://imgur.com/a/dqfVH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create fluid trapezoid image with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886337/how-to-create-fluid-trapezoid-image-with-css)

Comment: http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator